# Android WebView Font Face Not Initially Rendering

Tags: android, html, webview, font-face

I'm working on a mobile web app. The issue is apparent in some Android's (I think only 2.3.x phones).

There is a label and an input submit button on a page. Both are styled to have the same font face (TradeGothic, created by a @font-face style).
The label text always renders correctly however the button text never shows up the first time the page is visited.
So if you go to the page and either click on the button or go back and then forward (to the page in question) then the button text shows up fine.

I've tried resetting the value of the input button using jquery. I've also tried setting it's html and text however there are no changes.

What else can I try? (Besides losing the font.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by loading a dummy html page in the webview (in the background) while the app is starting up.

The dummy page consists of only the html for the button and it loads the same css file.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly hacky option, could you not use an image for the button which is using the desired font?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion however we found another hacky option. We're going with that to avoid special case images.